# Motor to spin slowly, low torque

Tags: dc-motor, torque, rpm

I am trying to find a motor to use to spin a cardboard wheel to drop balls through a hole. I want this to happen pretty slowly, around 10rpm. It also needs almost no torque, as it is spinning cardboard. However, when trying to find a motor, all I can find is extremely fast motors with low torque  or slow motors with high torque. Both options are expensive. Does a very low cost, DC, low speed, low torque motor even exist? Thanks

Comment: Google gear motors.. They come in all shapes sizes speeds and costs.

Comment: synchronous AC humidity drum motors or stepper motors and hobby servo motors can do this, otherwise you need servo feedback with rotary encoder.

Answer (score 1):

If you drive the wheel with a belt driven by a 2mm toy motor shaft turning at 5000 RPM you would need the pulley to be 100mm in diameter.

That sounds feasible. If you need the pulley to be bigger, put a small pulley on the motor. Easy to make if you have a small lathe, should be easy to make by sandwiching bits etc. if you don't.

---

If you're not in too much of a hurry you can get DC gear motors for << $10 from China like the below 12VDC 10RPM model with a convenient 6mm shaft.

[image]

This, like most gear motors, will have relatively high stall torque- it is 5.6 kg-cm rated.. if you need it to stall without damage you may need to limit the current.

Answer (score 1):

simple amazon search 10 seconds $4

https://www.amazon.ca/CNBTR-TYC-50-AC110V-Synchronous-Electric/dp/B01G8USUH0/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1504202443&sr=8-2&keywords=10+rpm+motor

[image]

Comment: +1 Ya that's what came to my mind first too Tony. Don't know if he wants to run it at 100V AC though.

Comment: Sounds like a Bingo machine with ping pong balls.  Torque may increase on jams and Synch. AC motor can start in either direction if that matters.